# hough transform line location (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

The [Hough line transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) witch is implemented in OpenCV can find the approximately line location (See the short lines in picture below).

[image: Found lines using OpenCV]

However, it can be seen in [Hough transform explanation](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/hough.htm) and [OpenCV's explanation of function](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html), it just finds the **r** and **theta**, which can't explain the short line locations.

Does Hough transform find anything more than **r** and **theta** which helps to find short line locations? How?

Comment: I suppose the visualization is the back projection of the valid votes.

Comment: @William, Excuse me; I can not understand you truly. Would you mind explain more?

Comment: You didn't study enough. OpenCV documentation code step 4b talks about a vector of lines with starting and ending points. Not theta and r.

Answer (score 1):

The Hough transformation and the probabilistic Hough transformation use the same technique to detect lines in an image. i.e. both calculate **r** and **theta** values. The difference between the two is the set of edge points that each algorithm uses. The probabilistic Hough transformation *randomly samples from the set of all the edge points* and uses them to detect lines, whereas the Hough transformation uses all the edge points in an image.

Now, this is my answer to your question. In the probabilistic Hough transformation, we take any two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) from the set of randomly selected edge points and calculate *(a,b)* using the following equations.

**y1 = x1(a) + b**

**y2 = x2(a) + b**

A pair of *(a,b)* essentially represents the line joining the two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2). In the code, we maintain a linked list that stores these *(a,b)* pairs and a count value associated with the pair. We calculate *(a,b)* values for all possible pairs from the selected edge points. While calculating *(a,b)*, we know corresponding edge points. In order to know which edge points contribute to each line, we can store these edge points. Then, we can compute the endpoints of each line in the image using this information.

Reference: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/AV1011/macdonald.pdf